# PHP Notice: String offset cast occurred line 251 & 258

Tags: php

i get php notice with this

```
$code = "";
while ($id > $length - 1) {
    // determine the value of the next higher character
    // in the short code should be and prepend
    $code = self::$chars[fmod($id, $length)] . $code; //<-- line 251
    // reset $id to remaining value to be converted
    $id = floor($id / $length);
}

// remaining value of $id is less than the length of
// self::$chars
$code = self::$chars[$id] . $code; //<-- line 258

return $code;
```

The NOTICE code is this part:

```
$code = self::$chars[fmod($id, $length)] . $code; 
$code = self::$chars[$id] . $code;
```

How to fix it? I can’t find it, please your help all.. :)

Comment: Where is the error? What is the error? Can you please be elaborate while asking questions

Comment: is my false, not error but PHP Notice, thx for attention & please your help ^^ @minocha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) should fix it:

```
..$chars[intval(fmod($id, $length))]..
```

---

That is caused because [fmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) returns a float, and it casts it to integer. See this example:

```
$a = 'abcdef';
$b = $a[1.0];
echo $b;
```

And the output:

> E_NOTICE : type 8 -- String offset cast occurred -- at line 3 
>   b

---

If you think about it (at least in this case), you can either be at position 1, or at position 2, for example. You can't be at position 1,5. So when you try to access something float, it automatically casts the value to integer and lets you know that it did that.